# Не знаю с чего начать делать метод

Tags: java, jsoup

У меня есть метод Document loadPage(String url): 
нужно, чтобы он, используя прокси (случайный активный прокси из списка), загружал страницу и возвращал ее. В случае, если не удалось загрузить, установить прокси active=false, и попробовать ещё раз (максимум 5 раз), если не получается - загрузить без прокси, если и так не получается вывести ошибку в консоль.

```
public Document loadPage(String url) throws Exception {

    Random random = new Random();

    proxies.get(random.nextInt(proxies.size()));
    if (proxies == null){
        boolean success = false;
        for (int count = 0; !success && (count < 5); ++count){
            try {
                success = true;
            }catch (Exception e){
                if (!success){
                throw new Exception("Attempts failed");
                }
            }
        }
    }else {
        Document document = Jsoup
                .connect(url)
                .proxy((Proxy) proxies)
                .get();
    }
    Document document1 = Jsoup
            .connect(url)
            .get();

  return document1;
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте начать с загрузки без прокси потом дописать все остальное.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

т.к. загрузка страницы используя прокси это тривиально и сводится к одной строчке (см https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html#proxy-java.net.Proxy- )

```
connection.proxy(proxy)
```

то проблема скорее всего в списке проксей.
начать ее решать можно как раз так как вы и описали:

1. загружаем начальный список
2. берем случайный элемент из списка
3. если он не активный, возвращаемся к пункту 2
4. грузим страницу с выбранным прокси
5. если получилось, то возвращаем документ
6. иначе, если если не сработало, помечаем этот прокси как неактивный,
7. и если мы еще не насчитали 5 ошибок загрузить страницу, то возвращаемся к пункту 2, иначе пытаемся без прокси (но это уже тривиально)

**дополнение 1**

итак, начало уже есть. это хорошо :)

теперь попробуйте, будет ли работать :)

забегая вперед замечу:

1. во второй строке вы грузите документ `Jsoup.connect(url).get()` без прокси, а по условию это надо делать только в конце
2. дальше `proxies.get(random.nextInt(proxies.size()))` берет случайны прокси из списка, но только один раз и про этом никуда его не использует
3. отсутствует проверка прокси на активность и деактивации т.к. нет и загрузки с прокси

а так очень даже неплохо для начала ;)

Comment: так?
public Document loadPage(String url) throws Exception {

        Random random = new Random();
        Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        proxies.get(random.nextInt(proxies.size()));
        boolean success = false;
        for (int count = 0; !success && (count < 5); ++count){
            try {
                success = true;
            }catch (Exception e){
                if (!success){
                throw new Exception("Attempts failed");
                }
            }
        }

      return document;
    }
@Ramiz

Comment: добавьте пожалуйста код к вопросу, в комментарии ну совсем не читабельно...

Comment: уже добавила...

Comment: можете проверить??

Comment: Proxy proxy = proxies.get(... и попытку с ним что то скачать надо бы внутри try{...} там где сейчас success=true сидит. При этом Proxy это будет ваш класс, который обернет java.net.Proxy и флаг active.